# Compare gallery item to string

Tags: powerapps

I got a gallery with Title and Subtitle, data source is from SharePoint List.
**Title:**

```
ThisItem.name_check_list
```

**Subtitle:**

```
ThisItem.user_mail
```

My example item Title is: **CQ 00.11/22**,
and my Subtitle is: **example.mail_qwe@mail.com**

When i use button with ***OnSelect*** action:

```
Select(Parent);
If(ThisItem.user_mail = "example.mail_qwe@mail.com", Navigate(BrowseScreen1, ScreenTransition.None), false)
```

Everything is ok, it navigates me to *BrowseScreen1*.
But when i use button with ***OnSelect:***

```
Select(Parent);
If(ThisItem.name_check_list = "CQ 00.11/22", Navigate(BrowseScreen1, ScreenTransition.None), false)
```

It returns false and i have no idea what I am doing wrong. I tried use ***Gallery1.Selected.name_check_list*** instead of ***ThisItem*** but without result.

Screenshots of my app:

[screenshot of app with tree view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djAy5.png)

[data source of gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKEco.png)

Screenshot with Title2.Text = "CQ 11.12/39":
[image]

Comment: Is the button where you have the `OnSelect` expression inside or outside the gallery? Can you post a screenshot of your app, including the tree view of the controls (on the left side of the canvas) - redacting any sensitive information that you don't want to share?

Comment: Button is inside the gallery, screenshots added in my question.

Comment: I tried recreating the same scenario (which you can donwload from https://carlosfigueira.blob.core.windows.net/public/StackOverflow51744626.msapp), and the navigation worked out fine. Is it possible that the data that you have has leading or trailing spaces, which would cause the comparison to fail? If this is the case, you can try using something like `If(Trim(ThisItem.name_check_list) = "CQ 00.11/22", Navigate(...`

Comment: I used Trim() and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. I've posted this as an answer, so that if other people stumble this same problem they should find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments in the question, you have leading and/or trailing spaces in the values in your list, which is causing the `If` condition to be evaluated to false.

You can use the [Trim function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-trim) to remove those spaces, and with that the expression should start working:

```
If(
    Trim(ThisItem.name_check_list) = "CQ 00.11/22",
    Navigate(BrowseScreen1, ScreenTransition.None))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I changed in your example:

```
Select(Parent);
If(name_check_list.Text = "CQ 00.11/22", Navigate(BrowseScreen1, ScreenTransition.None), false)
```

Try adding ".Text" to the comparison if that will do it.

Comment: I can't use ".Text" after name_check_list

Comment: "name_check_list" is the name of the control. For example, the subtitle control in your gallery is the text you try to compare, and the control name is "SubTitle". Then use "SubTitle.Text"

Comment: I used `Title2.Text = "CQ 11.12/39 "` but it still return false (added screenshot in question)